# Running a Powershell command to another ws that requires administrator privileges

Tags: powershell

I'm required to run a TPM command (requires admin access).

Lets use these for the legend:

1. Angelo - Standard user
2. AngeloAdmin - Admin user
3. Windows7 - Computer that has a standard user in it

How can I use my standard account to run the script as an Administrator to execute a script to another computer with a standard account **remotely**?

Heres the partial code I will run:

```
Set-Variable -Name BuildLog -Scope Global -Force
Set-Variable -Name Errors -Value $null -Scope Global -Force
Set-Variable -Name LogFile -Scope Global -Force
Set-Variable -Name Phase -Scope Global -Force
Set-Variable -Name RelativePath -Scope Global -Force
Set-Variable -Name Sequence -Scope Global -Force
Set-Variable -Name Title -Scope Global -Force

Function ConsoleTitle ($Title){
    $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = $Title
}

Function DeclareGlobalVariables {
    $Global:BuildLog = $Env:windir+"\Logs\BuildLogs\Build.csv"
    $Global:LogFile = $Env:windir+"\Logs\BuildLogs\TPM_On.log"
    $Global:Phase = "Final Build"
    $Global:Sequence = ""
    $Global:Title = "TPM Clear Ownership"
}

Function GetRelativePath { 
    $Global:RelativePath = (split-path $SCRIPT:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -parent)+"\" 
}

Function ClearTPM {
    #Declare Local Memory
    Set-Variable -Name ClassName -Value "Win32_Tpm" -Scope Local -Force
    Set-Variable -Name Computer -Value $env:COMPUTERNAME -Scope Local -Force
    Set-Variable -Name NameSpace -Value "ROOT\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftTpm" -Scope Local -Force
    Set-Variable -Name oTPM -Scope Local -Force

    $oTPM = Get-WmiObject -Class $ClassName -ComputerName $Computer -Namespace $NameSpace
    $Output = "Clearing TPM Ownership....."
    Write-Host "Clearing TPM Ownership....." -NoNewline
    $Temp = $oTPM.SetPhysicalPresenceRequest(5)
    If ($Temp.ReturnValue -eq 0) {
        $Output = "Success"
        Write-Host "Success" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    } else {
        $Output = "Failure"
        Write-Host "Failure" -ForegroundColor Red
        $Global:Errors++
    }
    Out-File -FilePath $Global:LogFile -InputObject $Output -Append -Force

    #Cleanup Local Memory
    Remove-Variable -Name oTPM -Scope Local -Force
}

Function ProcessLogFile {
    If ((Test-Path $Env:windir"\Logs") -eq $false) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Env:windir"\Logs"
    }
    If ((Test-Path $Env:windir"\Logs\ApplicationLogs") -eq $false) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Env:windir"\Logs\ApplicationLogs"
    }
    If ((Test-Path $Env:windir"\Logs\BuildLogs") -eq $false) {
        New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $Env:windir"\Logs\BuildLogs"
    }
    If ($Global:Errors -eq $null) {
        If (Test-Path $Global:LogFile) {
            Remove-Item $Global:LogFile -Force
        }
        $File1 = $Global:LogFile.Split(".")
        $Filename1 = $File1[0]+"_ERROR"+"."+$File1[1]
        If (Test-Path $Filename1) {
            Remove-Item $Filename1 -Force
        }
        $Global:Errors = 0
    } elseIf ($Global:Errors -ne 0) {
        If (Test-Path $Global:LogFile) {
            $Global:LogFile.ToString()
            $File1 = $Global:LogFile.Split(".")
            $Filename1 = $File1[0]+"_ERROR"+"."+$File1[1]
            Rename-Item $Global:LogFile -NewName $Filename1 -Force
        }
    } else {
        $date = get-date
        $LogTitle = $Global:Phase+[char]9+$Global:Sequence+[char]9+$Global:Title+[char]9+$date.month+"/"+$date.day+"/"+$date.year+" "+$date.hour+":"+$date.minute
        Out-File -FilePath $Global:BuildLog -InputObject $LogTitle -Append -Force
    }
}

Function ExitPowerShell {
    If (($Global:Errors -ne $null) -and ($Global:Errors -ne 0)) {
        Exit 1
    }
}

cls
GetRelativePath
DeclareGlobalVariables
ConsoleTitle $Global:Title
ProcessLogFile
ClearTPM
ProcessLogFile
Start-Sleep -Seconds 5
ExitPowerShell
```

Comment: Im not sure i fully understand the question. If i understand correctly, you basically want to have an elevated powershell remote session; like "Run as administrator", only remotely. Is this correct? Are you in a domain? Are you supplying custom credentials for the destination?

Comment: Yes we are in a domain and im an admin. I need to run a script using my admin credentials. Somewhat storing my admin or prompting my admin account everytime the script runs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the script as a different user you can 'SHIFT+Right click > Run as a different user' but that works only on applications, so you have to run Powershell as a different user and then the script, you can make a batch file to do that. Here is an example of what you will need in the batch file.

```
runas /user:yourdomain.com\administrator powershell
```

If you dont have a domain use the computer name

```
runas /noprofile /user:computername\administrator powershell
```